# При выборе option файл с помощью Ajax добавляется на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть выпадающий select.
Пользователь выбирает option, нажимает на кнопку и соответствующий файла с помощью Ajax добавляется на страницу

```js
$('.sel__submit').after('<div class="block"></div>');
$('select').change(function() {
  $('select').each(function() {
    var elemVelue = $('.sel').val();
    if (elemVelue == '1') {
      $('.block').append('<div class="block__1"></div>');
      $('.sel__submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        $('.block__1').load('1.html')
      });
    } else if (elemVelue == '2') {
      $('.block').append('<div class="block__2"></div>')
      $('.sel__submit').click(function(e) {
        $('.block__2').load('2.html')
      });
    } else if (elemVelue == '3') {
      $('.block').append('<div class="block__3"></div>')
      $('.sel__submit').click(function(e) {
        $('.block__3').load('3.html')
      });
    } else if (elemVelue == '4') {
      $('.block').append('<div class="block__4"></div>');
      $('.sel__submit').click(function(e) {
        $('.block__4').load('4.html')
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select" class="sel">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" class="sel__submit">
```

Все как бы работает.
Но меня попросили сократить код, чтобы без проверок value, чтобы select он сразу подсказал.
Я уже голову сломал, а придумать как его без проверок сделать так и не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы найти значение селекта, нужно пробежаться по опциям с selected атрибутом.

Добавьте в select: id="selectID"

```
var selectVal = $("#selectID option:selected").val();
```

И без jQuery наверное самый быстрый вариант, если работает:

```
var selectVal = document.getElementById("selectID").value;
```

И что-то вроде этого:

```
selectVal = parseInt(selectVal);
if (selectVal > 0) {
  $('.block').append('<div class="block__"'+selectVal.toString()+'></div>')
  $('.sel__submit').click(function(e) {
    $('.block__'+selectVal).load(selectVal.toString()+'.html')
  }
}
```

Comment: `$("#selectID").val();`

Comment: @Igor наверное от версии jQuery зависит, потому что встречал комментарии что так не работало